# How to use Mixin in main.js in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-mixin

I am trying to use global information from a mixin. I intend to access the `getNow` computed prop in a component, but it seems to be `undefined`.

*main.js:*

```js
Vue.mixin({
    data: function() {
        return {
          chainBoxURL: "http://172.22.220.197:18004/jsonrpc"
        }
    },
    computed: {
        getNow() {
          const today = new Date();
          const date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
          const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
          const dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
          return dateTime;
        }
    }
})
```

*Component:*

```js
methods: {
    getChainAddress(form) {
        if (form.password == form.password_again && form.password != '') {
            console.log(this.getNoW)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening? Are you receiving an error? What is the output of console log? Where are you including the mixin in the component? This isn't enough information to accurately determine what you need.

Comment: Thanks for listening. I need the getNoW method inside a client.vue component. However it is shown undefined.

Comment: The prop is defined as `getNow`, but your component tries to access `getNoW` (w/uppercase `W`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computed prop in the mixin is defined as: **getNow()** but youn spelt it as **getNoW()** within the component.

Either that or you may have forgot to include the mixin in the component.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is a typo in when you try to access `getNow`, there is a `W` instead of a `w`.

Side notes,

1. You could use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make life slightly easier

```js
const today = new Date();
const date = `${today.getFullYear()}-${(today.getMonth() + 1)}-${today.getDate()}`;
const time = `${today.getHours()}:${today.getMinutes()}:${today.getSeconds()}`;
const dateTime = `${date} ${time}`;
```

2. You can flip your conditions within the `if` statement as JS won't evaluate the 2nd one if the first one is false in case of an `&&`

```js
if (form.password != '' && form.password == form.password_again) {
  console.log(this.getNoW)
}
```